# joomla manifest creator

Tags: joomla

I've created an application for Joomla and now need to create the install manifest XML.

Anyone know of any good applications for building this?

My application has both fron-end and admin components, so I need something that can create the file paths for both.

I tried a couple I found on the internet, but they are all limited to getting one component, either the front end or the admin, but not both.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usuaully this is the first thing that needs creating to test the installation of your extension. Out of all honesty, you could just look the the manifest for another component and adapt it to your own needs.

Here is a basic one for Joomla 1.5 provided by Joomla! Docs: however change `version="1.5.0"` to whatever version of Joomla you are using

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1#Wrapping_It_All_Up_-_Creating_the_hello.xml_File

The might be a few things on there that you wont need.

Example of the folder structure to save time:

```
<files folder="admin">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>shoutbox.php</filename>
    <folder>swfupload</folder>
    <folder>views</folder>
    <folder>tables</folder>
    <folder>controllers</folder>
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>assets</folder>
    <folder>install</folder>
    <folder>packages</folder>
</files>
```

Comment: HEllo. I read all of that. The issue is the time it takes to get all the file names and paths into the XML file. It is a pain in the ass and seems like something someone would have created an app for by now.

Comment: don't write each file name separately. Instead, you can use `<folder> </folder>` which will add all the files within in. I have added an example to my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "duplicate" component using the [Component Creator for Joomla](http://www.component-creator.com) and use the manifest file from that.